# It is possible to pass jsp code as a parameter?

Tags: java, jsp, arguments

suppose I have a header (which is common for all pages regarding one type of object).

```
<%@ page session="false" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="header" uri="headerDir" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="tabs" uri="tabDir" %>
<div id="content" class="inside>
<header:myHeader headerData="${myModel}">
<tabs:myTabs argument="${someArg}"
....
```

so In views that are shared for different objects now I am doing

```
<c:choose>
     <c:when test="${myModel.type ==FIRST_TYPE}>
         <header:myHeader headerData="${myModel}">
      </c:when>
      <c:otherwise>
         <header:secondHeader headerData="${myModel}">
      </c:otherwise>
<c:choose>
```

but I would like to avoid this choose, I am able to send this
     
as a parameter as I am passing arguments? so can I do something like the following

```
<%@ page session="false" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="header" uri="headerDir" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="tabs" uri="tabDir" %>
<div id="content" class="inside>
<header:myHeader headerData="${myModel}">
<tabs:myTabs argument="${someArg}" headerToUse="${myHeader}" //in some way pass the header?
....
```

Comment: Have you tried having at least one view per only one type of model? Then common parts of such views can be encapsulated in separate files and mixed in the target page (e.g., by using inclusion or custom tags)

Comment: the thing is that only header is different, the rest is the same and to use one header or the other now I have a choose/when/test

Comment: Yes, I just suggested having one common.jsp, two jsps for headers and two jsps for models. Each model view should then include necessary header and the common part. Nevertheless, you can always hide your choose-when logic in a custom tag with `headerToUse` parameter just to make code cleaner.

Comment: It is how I have now, as I have written, I have the choose when, that's what I want to avoid for that reason I would like to send a parameter... otherwise I cannot avoid this choose/when (of course I can have it in a different tag) still the question is if I can pass the header as a parameter

Comment: You can have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/28193838/3425392 , but it seems there are no common way to do it. And such logic (including the idea of having one view for different models) does not seem to be common either. I'd rather try to refactor the code in general.

Comment: so there they are doing the same that I am doing now, but thanks for your inputs...